# Lenovo U460s screen dims constantly

Tags: windows, display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable autobrightness on Ideapad U460s (ubuntu)](https://superuser.com/questions/334498/disable-autobrightness-on-ideapad-u460s-ubuntu)

My screen dims constantly on the U460s. I have tried everything on the control panel and several ideas on the system but it still keeps dimming. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try booting into Windows and using the Lenovo power management settings to disable the ambient light sensor.